# QTP/UFT Capturebitmap save directly to Quality Center (QC)

Tags: vbscript, automation, qtp, hp-quality-center, hp-uft

So far All I have seen is different ways to save an existing image as an attachment to Quality Center (QC). That's fine, but is there a way to directly save an image as an attachment to Quality Center?

So for example, I have set specific areas in my automation framework to capture an image using something like:

browser("title:=.*").page("title:=.*").CaptureBitmap [fullname,override]

This would require to get the path of the folder in Quality Center, but I'm not sure how, is this possible? I would like to save it under a folder in the Test Plan section of Quality Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it! You can save it to the temp folder which exists on every machine. Then save it to QC!

```
    Dim oWsh, strTempFolderPath, strFilePathToSave, QCConnection, treeManager
    Dim LocalFilePath, Screen1, node, att, atta      

    Set oWsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    strTempFolderPath = oWsh.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
    strFilePathToSave = strTempFolderPath & "\Test1.png"

    browser("title:=.*").page("title:=.*").CaptureBitmap strFilePathToSave,True

    Set QCConnection = QCUtil.QCConnection
    Set treeManager = QCConnection.TreeManager
    ' Specify the local path to the file.

    LocalFilePath = strFilePathToSave

    ' Specify the Quality Center path to the desired folder
    Screen1 ="Subject\Path to the folder where you want to save it\"
    Set node = treeManager.nodebypath(Screen1)
    set att = node.attachments
    Set atta = att.AddItem(Null)
    atta.FileName = LocalFilePath
    atta.Type = 1
    atta.Post() 

    Set oWsh = nothing : set QCConnection = nothing : Set treeManager = nothing
    Set node = nothing : set att = nothing : set atta = nothing
```

Comment: My UFT hangs on the "Type" assignment. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

While the test is running, results are stored in a local temp directory. At the end of the run, the run result is uploaded to QC (and will be re-downloaded if you launch the result viewer to view the run result from QC).

**If you put your screenshots underneath that directory (maybe in a separate "screenshots" directory), your screenshots will be part of the run result stored in QC**, and thus will be viewable just like other run result entries.

You can get the local temp directory with:

`Environment.Value ("ResultDir") & "\Report\"`.

Everything stored under this directory is considered to be part of the run result and will be uploaded to (and made available in) QC.